# Edit all odd words in string to upper case

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to edit all odd words to upper case.

Here is sample of imput string:

```
very long string with many words
```

Expected output:

```
VERY long STRING with MANY words
```

I have this code, but it seams to me, that I can do it in better way.

```
<?php
$lines = file($_FILES["fname"]["tmp_name"]);

$pattern = "/(\S[\w]*)/";
foreach($lines as $value)
{
    $words = NULL;
    $fin_str = NULL;

    preg_match_all($pattern, $value, $matches);


    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i = $i + 2){

        $matches[0][$i] = strtoupper($matches[0][$i]);
        $fin_str = implode(" ", $matches[0]);
    }
    echo $fin_str ."<br>";
```

P.S. I need to use only preg_match function.

Comment: Please make an example with input and expected output

Comment: @Rizier123 check now.

Comment: Why do you need preg_match() only? There are other approaches too.

Comment: @Rizier123 its my task.

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment. Is your above code working?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes. Its working pretty well, but I think that I can do this in another way.

Comment: @KAMAEL You have to use `preg_match()` or you can?

Comment: @KAMAEL only use `preg_match` and why is that, simple string function should suffice like the answer below

Comment: @Ghost temporally deleted it until the smoke clears.

Comment: @Rizier123 can't understand the rationale behind it, most likely an assignment

Comment: @Ghost Maybe, especially when he ask it at 01:37 +01:00 AM :D So it would be for school tomorrow and he started at 1 o'clock with it!

Comment: Is it okay to use PHP function `preg_replace_callback` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 Bro, its for university

Comment: @KAMAEL So do you **must** use `preg_match` or do you **can** ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I must use preg_* functions with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `preg_replace_callback` example:

```
<?php

$str = 'very long string with many words';
$newStr = preg_replace_callback('/([^ ]+) +([^ ]+)/', 
     function($matches) {
         return strtoupper($matches[1]) . ' ' . $matches[2];
      }, $str);

print $newStr;
// VERY long STRING with MANY words

?>
```

You only need to match the repeating pattern: `/([^ ]+) +([^ ]+)/`, a pair of words, then `preg_replace_callback` recurses over the string until all possible matches are matched and replaced. `preg_replace_callback` is necessary to call the `strtoupper` function and pass the captured backreference to it.

[Demo](https://eval.in/316185)

Answer (score 0):

If you **have** to use regular expressions, this should get you started:

```
$input = 'very long string with many words';

if (preg_match_all('/\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)/', $input, $matches)) {

    $words = array();

    foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $odd) {
        $even = isset($matches[2][$key]) ? $matches[2][$key] : null;

        $words[] = strtoupper($odd);

        if ($even) {
            $words[] = $even;
        }
    }

    echo implode(' ', $words);
}
```

This will output:

```
VERY long STRING with MANY words
```

Answer (score 0):

You may don't need [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) simply use `explode` and concatenate the string again:

```
<?php

function upperizeEvenWords($str){
   $out = "";
   $arr = explode(' ', $str);
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
      if (!($i%2)){
         $out .= strtoupper($arr[$i])." ";
      }
      else{
          $out .= $arr[$i]." ";
      }     

   }
   return trim($out);

}

$str = "very long string with many words";

echo upperizeEvenWords($str);
```

Checkout this [DEMO](https://ideone.com/Cb1UdE)